# Fill blank Space with horizontal lines in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have dynamic jasper report. I need to fill out the blank space with horizontal lines (please refer the image). how to do that?

[image: sample report]

Comment: Arbitrary horizontal lines... or do they need to have sense to lines in table?, you can try to use the background band (but the lines will be arbitrary if you have stretch with overflow on some text field.....

Comment: yes i tried background band , but it overflows some times.. any other way..?

Comment: but it overflows?, background should not overflow.... it overlaps??

Comment: sorry..yes it overlaps.. apart from background band is there any other way  to do this.?

Comment: There is no simple way to do this in jasper report (how can jasper know how you lines should be created??), stretch with overflows make's you line move... The only solution I can come up with is using java loading modifying the JasperPrint object